# Drawing a check inside a checkbox using only css

Tags: css, checkbox

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox only using css and no images, but I am having a bit of trouble.

I followed a few tutorials online, but I seem to have hit a road block and help would be great.

My css looks like this

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #dee1e2;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  position: relative;
  bottom: .3em;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #dee1e2;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: .3em;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

What keeps happening is when I do the rotate the whole box rotates and I have tried adding a :after to it, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean but `-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);` remove this line if you don't want the checkbox to rotate.

Comment: Yes, I know that is what is causing it to rotate. The idea was to just rotate the white border so it looks like a check, but I'm having an issue with that.

Comment: Then I think you should pack the checkbox in some parent `div` and use that to create the border, rotate that div using `jQuery.change` on the checkbox and 'derotate' the box in the same function.

Comment: I'm trying to only use css and no jQuery. I have seen others do this I just cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: What is the final result supposed to be?

Comment: a check within a checkbox...

Comment: Don't checkboxes look like a check within a checkbox by default?

Comment: I am trying to create a custom one instead of using default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a unicode check, or even an icon font if you want to get really fancy...

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #dee1e2;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  position: relative;
  bottom: .3em;
}
/* added content with a unicode check */
input[type='checkbox']:checked:before {
  content: "\2713";
  left: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/brbcoding/pen/xFiLE)

Comment: Yeah, this is perfect! You rule! :)

Comment: @AmazingDreams this is true... Also doesn't look like there is anything that can really be done about it. Could style another element to *look* and act like a checkbox, but not the actual checkbox. If anyone knows of any good workarounds, that would be awesome.

Comment: It's a very good thing that I'm programming for an inhouse application where we can control what browsers they run! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact I tried the same thing on my website (http://e-home.mx) but I ended up hiding the input element with css and adding a label to each one which is the one that "emulates" its behavior like this:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c8" name="c8" />
<label for="c8"><span></span>Label here</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label{color:#000;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span{
 display:inline-block;
 width:19px;
 height:19px;
 margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background:url("http://e-home.mx/html5/img/form_elements_outlined.png") left top no-repeat;
 cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {display:none}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
 background:url("http://e-home.mx/html5/img/form_elements_outlined.png") -19px top no-repeat;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xedret/bTAGU/

Comment: This does work and is very useful (thank you for your answer!), but I was trying to do something that would not include any images of any sort.